# No me funciona la validación DataType.Currency en mi modelo

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Os comento, quiero poner una validación para introducir en un textbox un numero decimal:

```
[Display(Name = "Precio")]
[Range(1, 200)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "El valor introducido no es un valor de moneda válido.")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency, ErrorMessage = "El valor introducido no es un valor de moneda válido.")]
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Mi aplicación tiene puesta una globalización que funciona en casi todo: si selecciono en idioma "Inglés", me muestra las fechas en el formato americano, me muestra el símbolo $, me carga bien los archivos .resx y me traduce la aplicación… y cuando introduzco en el campo "Precio" un numero tal que "5.6" sí que me guarda correctamente la cantidad en la BD, ya que en ingles de américa, el decimal se marca con un "punto" y no con una "coma".

El problema lo tengo cuando cambio el idioma al español de España. La aplicación me la traduce genial, me pone las fechas en el formato de España… incluso los precios que ya tengo en la base de datos, me los muestra cambiando la el punto decimal por una coma, y el símbolo $ por un €. Pero cuando quiero introducir un un precio nuevo, es cuando tengo el problema, ya que si escribo "7,5", me salta la validación de que el valor introducido debe ser un número. Es decir, tengo dos problemas aquí:

- No me muestra la validación personalizada en "ErrorMessage = "El valor introducido no es un valor de moneda válido."
- A pesar de haber localizado y globalizado la aplicación, parece que en este caso, no parece reconocer la coma como el signo que delimita los decimales.

He visto varios temas al respecto en Stack Overflow, pero o no me funcionaban las cosas que proponían, o te mandaban a otros hilos que ya había probado…

Si queréis echar un vistazo, [os dejo el enlace a GitHub](https://github.com/erniker/TrainingNETCore/tree/master/MvcMovie).